# Need a Rollup summary on Account to look at a field on the Contact object. Need help with Declarative Lookup Rollups Summaries Tool

Tags: appexchange, roll-up-summary

I created a new field on the Account object called "Account Engagement"  I was trying to do a rollup summary on the Contact object but I can't.  Did some research on this and download the Tool Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool.  Just need help on how to set up it.  I have it in my sandbox.  The field I am looking up on the contact object is Mkto Lead Score.  This will be the sum of the lead score.  I have Account Engagement as a number field on Account.  Mkto Lead Score is a Number field on contacts. So There will be a field on the Account called Account Engagement and it will look at the Lead Score across all contacts on that account and add them together.

```
Parent Object:Account  
Child Object:Contact  
Relationship Field:AccountId  
Field to Aggregate:Mkto Lead Score  
Aggregate Operation:Sum  
Aggregate Result Field: Account_Engagement__c   
Calculation Mode:Realtime 
Calculation Sharing Mode:User
```

Error:

> Field to Aggregate: Field does not exist.

Updated the Field to Aggregate:mkto_si__Mkto_Lead_Score__c

ERROR
Error:
Error occured processing component dlrs__LookupRollupSummary2.Account Engagement. Custom Metadata Record Name: The Lookup Rollup Summary API Name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must be unique, begin with a letter, not include spaces, not end with an underscore, and not contain two consecutive underscores. (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION). Fields DeveloperName.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you had a look at the DLRS documentation and started building a rollup? You're on the right track and this should be a straightforward SUM rollup.

Comment: That's great, could you add this information to your question via an edit? I will add an answer below.

Comment: Hi Andre, please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That is not what comments are for.

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: I think the new error is pretty clear about what it's asking you to do. You need to change the Developer Name of your rollup.

Answer (score 2):

DLRS requires that you specify your **Relationship Field**, **Aggregate Result Field**, and **Field to Aggregate** by their API names, rather than their field labels. You've configured your rollup with

> Relationship Field: AccountId 
>   Field to Aggregate: Mkto Lead Score 
>   Aggregate Result Field: Account_Engagement__c

You are two-thirds of the way there. You need to specify the actual API field name for "Mkto Lead Score" as your Field to Aggregate, and DLRS should accept it. This will resolve the "Field does not exist" error.

The rest of your configuration looks correct, save that I usually suggest doing rollups with sharing mode set to System.

Comment: Is it possible to create declarative rollup summary on Affiliation object?